# Set a database value to null with a SqlCommand + parameters

Tags: .net, sql

I was previously taught today how to set parameters in a SQL query in .NET in this answer ([click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169359/improving-code-readability-for-sql-commands#169369)).

Using parameters with values are fine, but when I try to set a field in the database to null I'm unsuccessful. Either the method thinks I am not setting a valid parameter or not specifying a parameter.

e.g.

```
Dim dc As New SqlCommand("UPDATE Activities SET [Limit] = @Limit WHERE [Activity] = @Activity", cn)

If actLimit.ToLower() = "unlimited" Then
    ' It's not nulling :(
    dc.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("Limit", Nothing))
Else
    dc.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("Limit", ProtectAgainstXSS(actLimit)))
End If
```

Is there something I'm missing? Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

you want [DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx).Value.

In my shared DAL code, I use a helper method that just does:

```
    foreach (IDataParameter param in cmd.Parameters)
    {
        if (param.Value == null) param.Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
```

Comment: That's a really good solution. From now i will use it before all my Command.Execute() calls.

Answer (score 10):

I use a `SqlParameterCollection` extension method that allows me to add a parameter with a nullable value. It takes care of converting `null` to `DBNull`. (Sorry, I'm not fluent in VB.)

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static SqlParameter AddWithNullable<T>(this SqlParameterCollection parms,
            string parameterName, T? nullable) where T : struct
    {
        if (nullable.HasValue)
            return parms.AddWithValue(parameterName, nullable.Value);
        else
            return parms.AddWithValue(parameterName, DBNull.Value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string? optionalName = "Bozo";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithNullable("@Name", optionalName);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try setting it to `DbNull.Value`.