# Date changes to a vastly different value when saved into database

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, date, datetime

I'm trying to enter a date that's in a textbox into a column of `datetime` type

The code is as follows

```
    txtbookissue_date.Text = DateTime.Now.Date
    txtbookreturn_date.Text = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 7, DateTime.Now.Date)
```

When I Insert these two values into a database, (insert into book....) values such as `17-02-1984` show up in the database rather than, say, `26-2-2015`.

I did a little research and found out that SQL interprets it as "26 minus 2 minus 2015" rather than as a date.

Printing `Date(txtbookissue_date.Text)` gives correct results, the only problem is saving it into the database.

The solution for this was apparently to enclose the date in single quotes, i.e `'26-2-2015'` rather than just `26-2-2015`, Since I'm using a date function I decided to change

```
txtbookissue_date.Text = DateTime.Now.Date
```

to

```
txtbookissue_date.Text= "'"+DateTime.Now.Date+"'"
```

but It returns an error, something similar to 'cannot convert varchar type to date type, out of range exception'

How do I fix this? any help would be appreciated.

```
    txtbookissue_date.Text = DateTime.Now.Date
    txtbookreturn_date.Text = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 10, DateTime.Now.Date)

Protected Sub btn_issue_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_issue.Click
    con.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into Book (book_id, book_name, book_author,publisher,mem_id,mem_name,issue_date,return_date) values('" & txtbookissue_id.Text & "','" & txtibookssue_name.Text & "','" & txtbookissue_author.Text & "','" & txtbookissue_publi.Text & "','" & txtbookissue_memid.Text & "','" & txtbookissue_memname.Text & "'," & txtbookissue_date.Text & "," & txtbookreturn_date.Text & ")"
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx")
End Sub
```

Comment: your code will not compile. Show us the code you actually use.

Comment: show the code you are using to insert data into the database.

Comment: 17-02-1894, not 1984. Thank you.

Comment: txtbookissue_date.Text = Date.Now.Date
        txtbookreturn_date.Text = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 7, Date.Now.Date)

 Do While dr.Read
            txtbookissue_name.Text = dr("b_name")
            txtbookissue_author.Text = dr("b_author")
            txtbookissue_publi.Text = dr("publisher")
        Loop
        con.Close()
        txtbookissue_date.Text = Date.Now.Date
        txtbookreturn_date.Text = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 7, Date.Now.Date)
    End Sub

Comment: txtbookissue_date is a Textbox control? Then why not format your date object with ToString() or String.Format() instead of surrounding it with ' http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Comment: @StringerBell edit your code into the question, not into comments.

Comment: edited the code into the question. 

@Robin Gordijin, thanks i'll try that, and let you know soon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set a database value to null with a SqlCommand + parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170186/set-a-database-value-to-null-with-a-sqlcommand-parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are inserting date as a text. I mean while you need to insert it '2015-02-26' you are trying to insert it with another format. In fact you should use parameters with your sql query. Your sql statement should be something like that

```
insert into Book (book_id, book_name, book_author,publisher,mem_id,mem_name,issue_date,return_date) values(@book_id, @book_name, @book_author,@publisher,@mem_id,@mem_name,@issue_date,@return_date)
```

Before executing query you should set parameters in command object.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@return_date", DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 10, Date.Now.Date))
```

For more information about using parameters with access you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893837/using-parameters-inserting-data-into-access-database)

Comment: Thank you guys, using parameters worked like a charm, @fofik, your code worked, I didn't even have to break a sweat, just copied it and pasted it into my code, and then changed a few things :).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would highly suggest using [Paramaters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx).

Second, since you want to format your date into a string that is not the default culture. I would suggest you use String.Format() or ToString() ([examples](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)).

Since your database most likely expects a datetime. You could parse the string back to a DateTime using DateTime.ParseExact. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime) answer for a howto.

Let me know if this helps, if not you need to supply us with more info.

Comment: It seems like I just had to use Parameters for it to work, but I'll keep your examples link bookmarked, may come in handy, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting `string` in a `DateTime` column, please convert the values back to their original types before putting them in the database.

```
DateTime issueDate = DateTime.Parse(txtbookissue_date.Text);
DateTime returnDate = DateTime.Parse(txtbookreturn_date.Text);
```