# null to DBNull in AddWithValue using object variable in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, null, optional-parameters, dbnull

I am trying to make the optional parameter of a C# Method to be converted to `DBNull` (if it is `null`) to be added with Parameter.AddWithValue method.

I saw many solutions ([Set a database value to null with a SqlCommand + parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170186/set-a-database-value-to-null-with-a-sqlcommand-parameters)), extension methods, etc, but i wanted a single line solution.

`command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Municipio", municipio ?? DBNull.Value)`don't work (*Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DBNull'*)

The method: `public static void Foo(string bar, string municipio = null)`

Unfortunately i can't do `string municipio = DBNull.Value` because *"default parameter must be a compile-time constant"* (what i don't exactly understand the meaning).

I was able to make it work as such:

`object obj = municipio == null ? command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Municipio", DBNull.Value) : command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Municipio", municipio);`

I am very uncomfortable with this, seems like a JavaScript way of doing, i want something like:

`if municipio == null ? command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Municipio", DBNull.Value) : command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Municipio", municipio);`

But somehow i am not being able to make it work like this, perhaps im missing some syntax (i tried many parenthesis/etc combinations).

So my question is, is it good practice the one-line solution i reached, or should i replace it?

Comment: Another option is `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Municipio", municipio ?? DBNull.Value)`

Comment: I had tried it but `Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DBNull'`

Comment: Sorry. Should be `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Municipio", municipio ?? (object)DBNull.Value)`

Comment: This way works, but take a look here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41473095/dbnull-cast-to-object-returns-different-value) so i can better understand the difference of your "identical" answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated to handle if the variable is not initialized.**
Here is an example:

```
            OracleParameter P_COUNTYCODE = new OracleParameter("P_COUNTYCODE", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
            P_COUNTYCODE.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            P_COUNTYCODE.Value = countyCode.Length > 0 ? countyCode : (object)DBNull.Value;
```

try:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Municipio", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(municipio) > 0 ? municipio : (object)DBNull.Value)
```

Comment: This doesn't check if the value is null, which is what the question specifically asked for (quering the Length of a null value will throw a NullReferenceException)

Comment: This way works, but i am waiting for an answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41473095/dbnull-cast-to-object-returns-different-value) to better understand the observation @stuartd did.

Comment: thank you stuartd! i have updated my answer to handle if the variable was not set.