# DBNull cast to (object) returns different value

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, dbnull

I am trying to write `DBNull.Value` using `Parameters.AddWithVallue` when an optional parameter (a `string`) of a C# method is `null`.

```
public static void Abc(string distrito, string municipio = null)

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Municipio", municipio ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Municipio", municipio.Length > 0 ? municipio : (object)DBNull.Value);
```

However, `(object)DBNULL` returns two different values in two different **working** ways. One writes empty/null and other NULL.

[image]

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: "The image will be self-explanatory": When?

Comment: @Dillinger, Move images and code etc. into the questions. Don't bother us with links please.

Comment: Edited to include code, i just don't know how to use code on SO to make the image appear. Sorry. Someone edit for me.

Comment: In the editor, click "Add image" or read the SO tutorial.

Comment: The image was broken somehow; SO wouldn't upload it. I had to open it in the browser and screensot it. Weird. Anyway it's the same as the code so it doesn't matter.

Comment: OP, DO NOT paste in a screenshot of code. You had the actual text of the code. That was the best thing to do. Leave the text of the code as it is, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to make a few assumptions, but I think I know what's going on.  `municipio` is probably an empty string.  It is *not* null.

In that case, `municipio ?? (object)DBNull.Value` will be an empty string, *not* null.  However, `municipio.Length > 0 ? municipio : (object)DBNull.Value` has a value of `DBNull.Value`, which will generate a null in SQL Server.  In this case, if `municipio` is null, then this code will throw.  Since you say the code runs, I'm assuming that `municipio` is not null.

Comment: Question edited, it was messy at first. Check it please.

Comment: @Dillinger The answer is still correct.

Comment: @Dillinger This answer still applies.  I added a little more explanation of my assumptions.

Comment: It would not hurt to also mention the [correct approach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You are correct @recursive - it enters the method as an empty string, not `null`. So, for clarification on your answer, can you add to it that i should use: `AddWithValue("@Municipio", municipio.Length > 0 ? municipio : (object)DBNull.Value)`

Comment: @Dillinger:  That depends whether you want to store a 0-length string or `NULL` in your database in that case.